# BASH/shell script, fails to mount UFT-8 correctly (I think!)

Tags: bash, shell, utf-8, mount, fat32

I have a BASH shell script, in Linux, that mount drives.. I am running as 'root' all the time, and don't even have sudo or su installed, in case matters..

My problem is with UTF-8 filenames and directories, particularly on vfat partitions...

How do I mount each partition type with the correct options for UTF-8 filenames?

```
    TYPE="$(guess_fstype /dev/"${1}" 2>/dev/null)"
    # create mount point if it does not exist
    [ ! -e /mnt/$1 ] && mkdir -p /mnt/$1
   case $TYPE in 
        vfat) /bin/mount -t vfat /dev/$1 /mnt/$1 -o shortname=mixed,quiet,utf8 
            success=$? ;; 
        iso9660) mount -t iso9660 /dev/$1 /mnt/$1 -o utf8
            success=$? ;; 
        ntfs) mount -t ntfs /dev/$1 /mnt/$1
            success=$? ;; 
        unknown) mount /dev/$1 /mnt/$1 -o utf8 
            success=$? ;; 
        *) mount -t $TYPE /dev/$1 /mnt/$1
            success=$? ;; 
   esac
```

Comment: `man mount` has iocharset in the section for vfat.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly doesn't work? Is it mount, or is it listing files later on? Check your locale, maybe? And I think more or less all filesystems accept `utf8` option even if they have specific options for setting charset. Check `man mount`.

Comment: could you please post questions as comments. This is not an answer

Comment: Well, `Check your locale, maybe?` is not really a question. I did post a number of suggestions, why is it not an answer if it may be enough to solve the problem?

Comment: Haha. Now you have a few more options than initially, indeed. Initially you had 'a rant' on how you don't know what doesn't work, and then a blurt saying 'check you locale maybe'. Only. That was a little thin for an answer :)

Comment: Well, if I limited my first version to the question about what doesn't work I wouldn't even consider posting it as an answer (after all I'm not all that new here), but I really thought (and still think) that it's most likely shell locale issue.

Comment: it is mount itself that doesnt work - when browsing through the files and folders, anything with UTF08 characters in the name show as garbaged text..

Comment: How do you browse? What kind of garbage? If your locale set to non-utf8, it may be that you just can't see things. The same, BTW, goes for your terminal. Is it on console? Remote shell? xterm?

Comment: I browse with ROX file manager and with the termit terminal emulator.. I have briefly tested with other UTF-8 enabled terminal emulators as well.. they behaved the same as termit.. I have UTF-8 enabled locales.. I tested with Russian, Spanish, French, German and English (UTF-8 and no UTF-8)...

Comment: I'd start with 1. making sure your terminal emulator can do utf-8. That is — copy the file with utf8 to the computer and cat it.

Comment: 2. once terminal shows utf-8, I'd set locale (LC_CTYPE or LC_ALL) to en_US.utf8 (or similar — pick one from `locale -a` output). and would `ls` the directory in question. If it still shows garbage I'd be concerned.

Comment: My system is fine, I run in many different locales, UTF-8 and not...  it is simply the 'mount' commands that need checking - the only vfat partition I have is not repsonding the same AT ALL when compared to other devices that were mounted with these commands (results of those were posted elsewhere)...